# How to use NGXS Select() in an angular component

Tags: angular, typescript, ngxs

I've an angular project with NGXS that I just setup.

In my AuthState, I've the following:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthState {
  @Selector()
  static isAuthenticated(state: AuthStateModel) {
    return state.currentUser !== null;
  }
  //...
}
```

In a component, I'm doing the following:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Select(AuthState.isAuthenticated) isAuthenticated$: Observable<boolean>;
  //...
}
```

But it gives me a compilation error:

```
src/app/layout/header/header.component.ts:14:38 - error TS2564: Property 'isAuthenticated$' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

14   @Select(AuthState.isAuthenticated) isAuthenticated$: Observable<boolean>;
                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I totally understand why, here, angular has no way to know it will be properly initialized.

I've search a bit, and found a lot of link pointing to disable property initialization checks with

```
"strictPropertyInitialization": false
```

in the tsconfig.

But the thing is that I like this check, and I don't want to disable it. There has to be a way to not disable this for the whole application but still use NGXS Select's, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you dont want to change the setting. then you would have to set it via constructor.

```
constructor(store: Store){
    this.isAuthenticated$= store.select(AuthState.isAuthenticated);
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks! So no way to disable only for property without attributes or something like this?

Comment: well the setting indicates that you must initiate properties, you could potentially just disable the decorator setter for the individual bindings, but then it defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 5):

If you are sure that you don't want to initialize your property, you can use Typescript non-null assertion operator (!), before the type of your property :

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Select(AuthState.isAuthenticated) isAuthenticated$!:Observable<boolean>;
  //...

}
```

It should get rid of the compilation error.
This operator is like telling TypeScript : I know this property will not be undefined, please don't yell at me :D

It allows you to keep your decorator, instead of moving your initialization to the constructor + you can keep your "strictPropertyInitialization" setting.

Comment: Yes it does, but it just basically says to the compiler to not check it, which I'm not a big fan. Thank you for the answer